# Nodejs, Is there anyway to load only the head part of a Html url?

Tags: html, node.js, url

i want to prevent loading the rest of the page and just load the -head-, in case the page be too heavy and i just need the -title- so thats a total waste. any idea if this is possible or not?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another not-so-clean solution (in addition to [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75660632/7575111)) is to "stream" the site to a buffer in chunks and abort once `</head>` is reached. The problem is, the last chunk could still contain more than just `</head>`. Should work nonetheless:

```js
const https = require("https");

const options = {
  hostname: "stackoverflow.com",
  path: "/",
  method: "GET",
};

const req = https.request(options, res => {
  let buf = Buffer.alloc(0);

  res.on("data", chunk => {
    buf = Buffer.concat([buf, chunk]);
    const headEndIndex = buf.indexOf("</head>");
    if (headEndIndex !== -1){
      buf = buf.slice(0, headEndIndex + "</head>".length);

      console.log(buf.toString());

      res.destroy();
    }
  });
});

req.end();
```

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can come is to use the [`content-range` request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Range) to ask the server for a specific number of bytes.

The specifics of how to do this depends on the HTTP API (`node:http`, `fetch`, `axios`, etc.) you are using.

Limitations:

- You have to guess how many bytes will be enough to get the entire `<head>`. This is hard. For example `http://facebook.com` gives me 27K of data before the end of `</head>` while `http://example.com` only has 940B.
- Not all servers support `Content-Range`

Comment: im just new at these so this may be a silly question but i know we can make a stream of data so is it possible to stream an check it at the same time and as soon as we have a complete `<head></head>` just stop loading more?

Comment: @shiyonsufa Chances are the full response is already on its way to you regardless of whether you figure out how to cancel the stream.